# Domain of $\ln\left(\frac{6}{6+x-x^2}-1\right)+\arcsin\left(\frac{x+1}{3}\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, logarithms, principal-ideal-domains, inverse-function

blob:https%3A//mail.google.com/ea67134d-45a0-4cc0-9ec7-abf6d5a50852

I believe that my first condition is wrong but I don't understand why. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Did I edit this correctly?

Comment: Also welcome to math stack exchange. You should show how you attempted to solve the problem and what you know about it so far. Lastly this site uses mathjax which you can find here at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for typing equations.

Comment: Yes you have edited it well. I've shown my attempt in the link.

Comment: I tried your link but could not get in. You should instead type out the attempt in your post.

Comment: https://scontent-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtf1/v/t34.0-12/12919032_10209245001271423_955743984_n.jpg?oh=ac48ef4ea74708122c3e709342599ab4&oe=5701E5C1

Comment: Thank You.  Next time be sure to type this all out instead of giving a cellphone pic. This way users here won't downvote your question. This may be tedious at first but will useful for publishing mathematics in the future.

Comment: Is my answer unclear?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the domain of $\arcsin\left(\frac{x+1}{3}\right)$ being $[-4,2]$ but not the domain of $\ln\left(\frac{6}{6+x-x^2}-1\right)$.

After you take the roots make sure to find which outputs of $\left(\frac{6}{6+x-x^2}-1\right)$ between each root is positive or negative. Also evaluate the outputs of the roots themselves.

$x=-2,0,1,3$

If it is negative the values are undefined. For example if we take $\ln(-2)$ it is undefined.

You should end up with $(-2,0)\bigcup(1,3)$

Now compare this to the arcsin domain $[-4,2]$. Remeber when adding both equations if you add an undefined amount to a defined amount it is still undefined because the value is still complex. (To clarify this $\ln(-2)+\arcsin(\frac{4}{3})$ is undefined ).

So when adding both equations you should end up with
$$(-2,0)\bigcup(1,2]$$